# Not maximum CPU and GPU utilization in Fortnite

Tags: performance, fortnite-battle-royale

I have the following problem:

I have set 240 FPS in Fortnite. However, these are never reached constantly. Most of the time they are at 100-150 FPS. However, my CPU and GPU are BOTH underutilized. Thus it does not seem to be a bottleneck problem.

My components are:

- Mainboard: MSI B450M PRO-VDH PLUS
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- GPU: NVIDIA Geforce RTX 2060
- RAM: 2 * 8 GB DDR4
- Power supply: 500 Volt
- Operating system: Windows 11
- Monitor: 280 HZ

The temperature of my processor are during the game at about 60 degrees and my GPU at 50 degrees. I have already installed the latest drivers for all components and adjusted the settings for maximum performance in the Windows settings.

Nevertheless, I don't get to the 240 FPS in the rounds in Fortnite, although none of my components is fully utilized (see picture). Does anyone happen to know what my problem could be and how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot!

[image: Task manager during playing Fortnite]

Comment: I see you said you adjusted performance settings, but Are you by chance in a power saving mode state? Check your power options in windows

Comment: @TimmyJim I have selected ultimate performance as power mode on windows

Answer (score 0):

Fortnite is known to mostly only use a few of the processor's cores. However, it seems that your cores are only around 50% which is bizarre.

The GPU waits for the CPU to finish its tasks before rendering the next frame. So I would try using more CPU resources first.

- Do you have XMP (or DOCP) enabled in your BIOS ? If not activate it.
- Do you have an intensive app with higher priority running in background ?
  Try putting Fortnite in a higher priority mode.
- Check if you can use all of your system resources with a benchmark.
- NVIDIA Control Panel 3D settings: Ensure that the power management mode is set to "Prefer maximum performance" and that the maximum pre-rendered frames are set to "1".

Comment: I have already implemented your points 1,2 and 4. I will try run a benchmark. Thanks anyway for your suggestions :)